# How to split widgets in Wordpress Sidebar?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sidebar

i want to make every widget that is placed in my Wordpress sidebar to be splited with extra spacing, just like is in this [demo site](https://www.betrush.com/verified/). This is mine current [sidebar](http://definitiv.cz/) . Any tips how to do that? i tryed all CSS codes that find on net, but none of them help me. This is PHP for that sidebar.

```
<?php
/*
Template name: Page - Right sidebar
*/
 get_header(); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'flatsome_before_page' ); ?>

   <div class="page-wrapper page-right-sidebar">
   <div class="row">

  <div id="content" class="large-9 left col col-divided" role="main">
  <div class="page-inner">
    <?php if(get_theme_mod('default_title', 0)){ ?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title mb uppercase"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <?php } ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ){
                    comments_template(); } ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </div><!-- .page-inner -->
 </div><!-- .#content large-9 left -->

<div class="large-3 col">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- .sidebar -->

</div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .page-right-sidebar container -->
<?php do_action( 'flatsome_after_page' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
#sidebar li.widget-container{
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Background color of widgets:

```
#sidebar_container{
    background:transparent;
}
```

Where `sidebar_container` is Your container for sidebar.

EXAMPLE:

```
<aside id='sidebar_container' class='col-md-4 right'>
    <ul id='sidebar' class='right'>
        <?php
            if ( is_single() || is_page() ){
                if ( is_active_sidebar('Single Sidebar') ){
                    dynamic_sidebar(esc_html__('Single Sidebar','my-theme')); 
                }
            }else{
                if ( is_active_sidebar('First sidebar') ){
                    dynamic_sidebar(esc_html__('First sidebar','my-theme'));    
                }
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Padding and margin change:

```
.col-border+.col,.col-divided+.col {
    padding-left: 10px!important;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top:-15px;
    /* margin-left:-100px; */
    display: inline-table;
    /* padding-right: 60px; */
}
```

Comment: That only add spacing between widgets. I asking for separated with background color between each other, like is shown in image. Tnx.

Comment: it add margin not spacing. Look at edited answer. There You can set background for sidebar or use "transparent" and then sidebar will have backoground of body or parent div.

Comment: I placed both your CSS into custom CSS editor but dont see blue background color between widgets. There are 2 widgets placed into sidebar currently on my site. Also set color to background CSS but nothing happens.

Comment: Edited first post.

Comment: You must set background for ".large-3.col { background:transparent } but then You must set background white for all Your widgets -  .widget{background:#ffffff;'}

Comment: That make sense. How to extend now widget space to be the same as menu ribbon width ?

Comment: look at edited answer but I'm unable to help with all ... You just need to use CSS to makes it look good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148235/discussion-between-drmtr-and-michael).

Answer (score 1):

```
Footer.php
<style>
#footer-sidebar1 {
border: 1px solid red;
float: left;
width: 32.5%;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
}
#footer-sidebar2 {
border: 1px solid red;
float: left;
width: 32.5%;
margin-right:5px;
}
#footer-sidebar3 {
border: 1px solid red;
float: left;
width: 32.5%;
} .
widget_bac{ background-image: url("http://localhost/wordpress/wpcontent/uploads/2017/07/footer.jpg");}
h3.w_hed {
color: white;
}
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="footer-sidebar" class="secondary widget_bac" style="border: 1px solid
blue; height: 400px;">
<div id="footer-sidebar1">
<?php
if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1')){
dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1');
}
?>
</div>
<div id="footer-sidebar2">
<?php
if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-2')){
dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-2');
}
?>
</div>
<div id="footer-sidebar3">
<?php
if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-3')){
dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-3');
}
?>
</div>
</div>
Function.php
/*******************************************************************************/
function tesseract_widgets_init() {
register_sidebar( array(
'name' => 'Footer Sidebar 1',
'id' => 'footer-sidebar-1','description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</aside>',
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
'name' => 'Footer Sidebar 2',
'id' => 'footer-sidebar-2',
'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</aside>',
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
'name' => 'Footer Sidebar 3',
'id' => 'footer-sidebar-3',
'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</aside>',
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'tesseract_widgets_init' );
/*******************************************************************************/
```